# WordPress Admin Panel Problems

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Currently I’m using WordPress Version 6.3 and whenever I log into my admin panel dashboard it seems fine until I click on any option. It redirects me to my home page but has a different url at the top. I’m unable to access anything via dashboard so I have to resort to FTP. Please let me know if anyone has any potential solutions for this problem, thank you.

I’ve tried disabling the plugins and themes but doing both had no impact or change on the dashboard.

Video of the problem: youtu.be/d0MLo_fzcu0

Answer (score -1):

Try defining site constants in `wp-config.php` as described here:

> It is possible to set the site URL manually in the wp-config.php file.
>
> Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where “example.com” is the correct location of your site.
>
> `define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );`
>
> `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );`
>
> This is not necessarily the best fix, it’s just hard-coding the values into the site itself. You won’t be able to edit them on the General settings page anymore when using this method.

https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/#edit-wp-config-php

Comment: This would work for the admin dashboard links?

Comment: Could be. The situation you describe isn't very clear, and this is the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Is there anything I can send to better determine what could be the problem?

Comment: Adding example URLs to your question could help us understand the issue and get pointed in the correct direction.

Comment: Sorry for the late response; I just did a quick screen recording to demonstrate what I'm experiencing.

https://youtu.be/d0MLo_fzcu0